# extracting numbers from in a string

Tags: php, regex

I need to create an array of integers from strings of text composed of the integers separated by whitespace and plus signs, for example

```
$string = "1 + 2 + 3 + 4";
```

is extracted into

```
$array = ('1' , '2' ,'3' , '4');
```

This needs to be done in php.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you provide any code attempt? It will be helpful..

Comment: This site is for programming questions. It is not a code writing service. You show what you've attempted, we (maybe) try help fix it.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, this is the first time I have posted a question, I should have paid closer attention to the guidelines!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankyou for the question refinment.

```
<?php

$string = '1 + 2 + 3';
$array = explode(' + ', $string);

for ($a=0;$a<count($array);$a++){
  $array[$a] = (int) $array[$a]; // RECAST STRING TO INTEGER
}

?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I think I need to explain myself better.

I have strings composed of an indeterminate number of integers separated by whitespace and plus signs, ie $string = "1 + 2 + 3 + 4 ";

I need to extract just the integers from these strings into an array , ie $array = ('1','2','3','4');

Comment: Thanks for the update, the above now covers it i think. Including the recast to integer datatype.

Answer (score 0):

To get the array you need to use PHPs `explode` function, which will split a string into an array by a delimiter, for example:

```
$integerString = '1 + 2 + 3 + 4';

$integerArray = explode(' + ', $integerString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use preg_match_all!

```
<?php
$string = '1 + 2 + 3';

preg_match_all("'[0-9]+'sim", $string, $out);

print_r($out);
```